# How to avoid duplicate token evaluation?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I use Keycloak 4.1.0.Final with Spring Boot 2 and I want to authenticate to a rest endpoint `/services/{some id}/content/{id}` with a bearer token. I have taken the setup from here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.1/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_boot_adapter

On the Keycloak server I have created a resource `/services/123/content/{id}` so that only access to entity with id=123 can be granted. All others shall be denied.

Now, when I call the endpoint with a bearer token, the token is evaluated twice. First, through the `KeycloakAuthenticatorValve` which grants access:

05-16-2019 16:04:40 DEBUG org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.AbstractPolicyEnforcer - Authorization GRANTED for path

Second, through the `KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter` which denies access:

05-16-2019 16:04:42 DEBUG org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.KeycloakAdapterPolicyEnforcer - Authorization denied - @[,http-nio-8081-exec-1@304]

I have seen that the `AbstractPolicyEnforcer` called from `KeycloakAuthenticatorValve` uses the path `/services/123/content/{id}` for evaluating the permission. The path is also registered on the Keycloak server.

But the `AbstractPolicyEnforcer` called from `KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter` uses only the context path `/services` which is not registered on the Keycloak server. So the permission cannot be granted.

Does anyone know why the token is evaluated multiple times? Can this be disabled?